# Do I need a Hong Kong transit visa if I travel to Shenzhen via Hong Kong airport?

Tags: transit, china, hong-kong, pakistani-citizens, shenzhen

I am a Pakistani national living and working in Germany. I need to travel to Shenzen for business and the easiest route is to fly to Hong Kong and then take the ferry to Shenzen (no entry into Hong Kong).

My question is do I need a Hong Kong transit visa to do this?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, you do need a visa.  While *almost* everybody can transit through HKIA visa-free, Pakistani passport holders [belong to the "^" group](http://www.immd.gov.hk/en/services/hk-visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html) where:

> All nationals (except holders of Diplomatic and Official passports)
>   are required to hold a valid visa for the HKSAR for whatever purpose
>   (including those who are in transit and remain on the airside).

This applies even for a direct transfer via Hong Kong International Airport, and thus includes the [SkyPier direct ferries to Mainland China](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/transport-connection-with-mainland-china/ferry-transfer/service-at-a-glance.html) that [do not need](http://www.hongkongairport.com/leaflet/skypier.pdf) to pass through HK immigration.